# SSRS parameterized query slow on Sharepoint

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services

Having an issue when running a report with a cascading parameter on Sharepoint. 
After you enter the first parameter (`@Suburb`) it takes approx. 10sec before displaying the drop-down list of postcodes. Running `SQL Server Profiler` I can see that the actual query returns in 9ms.

The dataset is just a query, not a stored procedure, for the second parameter and looks like this:

```
SELECT PostCode
FROM SuburbData
WHERE Locality = @Suburb
```

So far I have tried the following answers found on here, such as assigning the parameter to a variable like so:

```
DECLARE @Locale CHAR(100)

SET @Locale = @Suburb

SELECT PostCode
FROM SuburbData
WHERE Locality = @Locale;
```

Adding the `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` hint to the end of the query.

Creating a stored procedure of the above query.

The parameter is of data type TEXT.

Why the delay in displaying the result?

Comment: How many records get returned to fill the dependent parameter (`PostCode`)? If there are a lot, rendering that could take some time.

Comment: In most cases there is only one, some are up to 20+ but it takes the same if it return 1 or 20+.